# Auto update time with setInterval() in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am on a project where I am storing date and time(in_time and out_time) in a database table for a web page. What I actually want is to keep adding 2 minutes to the out_time column after every two minutes till the web page is closed or if a user moves away from the page by any means. I have been making `AJAX` requests but it doesn't shows any effect on the database 'out_time' column. May I know what wrong I am doing here?

This is the script that I am using on the web page whose time I want to record:

```
   <?php include 'blocks/leftnavInc.php' ; ?> 
<?php

    if(isset($_REQUEST['chapterId']) && $_REQUEST['chapterId']!='')
    {
        $chapterId      =   $fnc->decode(trim($_REQUEST['chapterId']));
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['moduleId']) && $_REQUEST['moduleId']!='')
    {
        $moduleId=$fnc->decode(trim($_REQUEST['moduleId']));
    }
  $uid      =   $_SESSION['session_user_id'];

  ?>
      </div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    function out_ajax(){
    $.ajax({ 
      type:"POST",
      url:"out_time.php",
      success:function(html){
       }   
        });
    }

    window.setInterval(function(){
        out_ajax();
    }, 120000);
});
    </script> 
  <?php 
  $inTime       =   date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $outTime    =   date("Y-m-d h:i:s");    
    $difference =   strtotime($outTime)-strtotime($inTime);
    $created    =   date("Y-m-d");
    $dataTime   =   array("user_id"=>$uid, "module_id"=>$moduleId, "chapter_id"=>$chapterId,"in_time"=>$inTime, "out_time"=>$outTime, "created"=>$created);
    $db->query_insert("tbl_ppt_time", $dataTime);
  $_SESSION["last_id"]  = mysql_insert_id(); 
  ?> 
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 page-right">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_question_module", "title", $moduleId) ; ?>
          <a href='studyMaterial.php?moduleId=<?php echo $_REQUEST['moduleId'];?>' class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 75%;margin-top: -24px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Go Back Study Material</a>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
<div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer"  data-url="../sadmin/studyMaterial/<?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "file_ppt", $chapterId) ; ?>"> </div>
 </div>  
<div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="left_panel" class="clearfix left">
              <div class="leftNavigation">
                <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content">
<?php
$sq             =   $db->query("SELECT id, title from tbl_question_module WHERE status = 1");
while($rowM=mysql_fetch_array($sq))
{
?> 
    <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rr<?php echo $rowM['id'] ; ?>" class="collapsed "> <a href="#"><?php echo $rowM['title'] ; ?> <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="rr<?php echo $rowM['id'] ; ?>">
<?php $fnc->getModuleChaptersppt($rowM['id']) ; ?>  
</ul>
</li>
<?php } ?> 
</ul>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
        </div></div>
    </div>
```

And further my out_time.php looks like this:

```
<?php
@session_start();
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo '';
mysql_select_db( 'dbname' );

$uid = $_SESSION['session_user_id'];
$moduleId = $_REQUEST['module_id'];
$chapterId = $_REQUEST['chapter_id'];
$last_id = $_SESSION["last_id"];

$update_time = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_ppt_time SET out_time = now() WHERE id='$last_id'  AND user_id = '$uid' AND module_id='$moduleId' AND chapter_id='$chapterId'");
?>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks to the community in advance.

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: You are not sending params in your ajax ` $_REQUEST['module_id'];$_REQUEST['chapter_id'];$_REQUEST['seconds'];` . Your update condition `module_id='$moduleId' AND chapter_id='$chapterId'"` is failing because of that.

Comment: you aren't sending any data to the server. You need to add a `data` parameter to the ajax options containing the appropriate info, which presumably is held elsewhere in your page. And you aren't using $time_taken in the query either. I don't know if you intended that or not.

Comment: @VijayRathore Thank you for the time. But may I know what I need to change in here. I mean where I need to make changes and with what. I am new to AJAX and Jquery so please accept my apologies.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the concern mate. I just need to update the out_time in the database, so what parameters do I need to send? The UPDATE query written here is the only thing I want to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As vijay said, in order to run the query properly you need to get values for Module ID and Chapter ID, as they are needed your WHERE clause so SQL knows which row to change. In order to suggest what to do, we need to know where this information is held? At the moment you're expecting the ajax call to send it in the request, but it does not send any parameters. Can the Javascript retrieve this information from the page somewhere (e.g. in a HTML element, or in a JS variable) and use it in the ajax call? Or it should it come from somewhere on the server? We don't know how your application works.

Comment: Secondly, if you're just needing to update `time_out` to the current date/time, then presumably you don't need to collect `$time_taken` at all? Currently your PHP code tries to collect it from the ajax request, but then doesn't use it for anything. Can you confirm that this is redundant? The same goes for `$created` as well.

Comment: @ADyson Yes these two variables are redundant. I removed them and edited the code.

Comment: @ADyson I have edited the question with the whole code for that page. Now can I get a better insight please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your main page fetches the chapter ID and module ID from the request, and they don't change through the life of the page, you can simply inject these into the Javascript for later use as parameters to send with the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type:"POST",
  url:"out_time.php",
  data: { "chapter_id": "<?php echo $chapterId; ?>", "module_id": "<?php echo $moduleId; ?>" },
  success:function(html){
  }   
});
```

P.P.S your main page checks whether chapter ID and module ID are present in the query string, and then decodes them. But what if they aren't? It just carries on regardless, and I guess it would probably crash. It ought to have better error handling, but that's a separate task.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. No they are not numeric, but a string of alphanumeric. Although when a particular chapter is clicked, the URL does sends a query string in URL.Let's see to that later, but thanks again. I am checking if this works or not and I will get back to you.

Comment: Ok I amended it with quotes to make JS understand them as strings. Just because another bit of code sends the correct data, doesn't mean a user or hacker might try to go directly to your page without the correct values (or worse, with deliberately malicious ones - hence my warning about injection attacks)

Comment: Yes you are right, I will certainly keep this in mind and will work on this. But coming back to the topic unfortunately the out_time is not changing after interval of 2 minutes. Something more can be done?

Comment: I'd need a bit more info than that to understand the problem. "Not working" could mean anything. You need to trace the flow of control and debug what's happening. Start from the beginning: Does the ajax request  get executed? Does it succeed? What HTTP response do you get (check your browser's network tab, in the developer tools, and look for the ajax request to see the status and examine the response)? Do the fields get sent successfully in the request body? If so, then echo your SQL string before you run it - does it look right? Does it work if you run it in MySQL directly?

Comment: This is all basic debugging of your web application, which you should be familiar with, regardless of previously using ajax or not.

Comment: Another side point on security: Using the "root" account to log your web app into the database is a _terrible_ idea. root can do whatever it likes. Combined with your current SQL injection vulnerabilities, someone could easily write code to destroy all the data and databases held in MySQL, delete all the users, change the passwords etc etc. It's an open book. Create a separate user account specifically for this application which only has permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work correctly.

Comment: yes sure. I am tracing this. Thanks for your valuable information. Give me sometime, looking into the matter

Comment: Something else that might help with debugging: According to the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) it says "mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error." So `$update_time = mysql_query(` doesn't make much sense. You won't get any kind of time returned from it. Instead do `$success = mysql_query(` , and then `if ($success == false) { echo mysql_error(); }` which will output any error messages into the ajax response. You can also run `mysql_affected_rows() ` to see how many rows got updated, if you need to.

Comment: It seems its not getting into the script tag at all. I tried doing with an 'alert' but flow is not getting into the <script>.  What could be the pssibility for this

Comment: Are there any error messages in your browser's console? The JS code as shown should work, as long as you've included jQuery in the page. Don't forget the function won't actually get run until 2 minutes have elapsed.

Comment: No, there are no error messages into console. And as I said, if the flow was getting into the <script> then alert() should have evoked but it didn't.

Comment: Can we connect through email if you don't mind providing it here?

Comment: Actually there was a typo in my code above (i've corrected it). Should be `data: ` with a `:`. You should have been getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" (or similar depending on your browser) in your console. Are you definitely looking in the right place?? Try again with that corrected.

Comment: And no, with all due respect I don't give out my email address to strangers online. This forum is perfectly sufficient for exchanging information, and has the added benefit of being publicly available to others to learn from in future. We can move it to a discussion chat if it gets overly long. I'm volunteering while on this site. If you want to do it privately we can discuss my consultancy rates... ;-)

Comment: Ah yes, I just saw it on console as syntax error, SyntaxError: missing : after property id
 

data { "chapter_id": "11", "module_id": "2" },

Comment: ok great. So correct that and run it again and see what happens.

Comment: Sigh of relief. IT WORKS !! Thanks a ton to you. Many thanks , Heartly thanks !! :)

Comment: But there comes an issue again. I am checking this on local system and by the script whenever I am making an entry into the database it records time 5 and half hours behind from my local time. Now when the AJAX runs and the time changes it adds +5:30 to the out time. i.e when a record is made, it shows in_time and out_time as 2017-09-21 11:35:41, now when AJAX runs, the in_time remains same(as expected) but the out_time shows 2017-09-21 17:12:41 and this time is the actual time at my country.

Comment: Ok that's quite a complicated issue involving timezones. If you accept this answer for the question of how to get the ajax working, then post a new question explaining the timezone issue in detail, I think you'll get better help from multiple people. If you link to the new question from here I will have a look as well.